# Save current HTML5 video time with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Mudar para português
I'm developing a project, something like Netflix, where the logged in user can continue watching the last watched episode, however I need to save the current time of the video, so I wanted to know if there is any method in js that retrieves the current time before the user close the page or go back to the home page, I really do not know how to do this without making too much request to the bank, I thought about saving at intervals of time, but I would also be using a lot of firebase resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I strongly recommend use video.js. Then you can get current time of the video like this if you don"t use video.js

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var currentTime = vid.currentTime;
```

in video.js

```
var currentTime = player.currentTime();
```

Then you can save it where you want but I strongly recommend you localStorage. It is something like this.

```
localStorage.setItem('your_video_identifier', currentTime);
```

And last of all you can call it in every second with setInterval or you can call it beforeunload event in jquery something like this.

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    var currentTime = vid.currentTime;
    localStorage.setItem('your_video_identifier', currentTime);
    return; 
});
```

or

```
var currentTimeSaver = setInterval(function(){
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        var currentTime = vid.currentTime;
        localStorage.setItem('your_video_identifier', currentTime);
}, 1000);
```

If you still want to use firebase you can check this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: but I believe that the beforeunload event is already good for me, I'm going to do the tests

Comment: Thank you for your response, the onunload event served me well.